# SQL/SSIS 12h Performance issue only on one server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ssis

I have a SSIS package with an OLE DB source and an OLE DB destination. Both are connected to the same database. The source is a query from a staging table, some left join and conditions. We truncate the destination table every time and load approximately 30 0000 000 rows.

The issue is the SSIS package is now running more than 12h in the production server, but approximately 45 minutes in the dev and test server.

The last modification we did when this issue occurred was added a left join, on the same staging table as the from, a new column and a condition in the where. To add a little more context, the staging have two rows for a sale, one for the sale and optionally one for the refund. So from now, the destination table have only one row for the sale and a new column for the refund number, instead of two rows for the same sale. The left join on the staging is to find the refund number. We added an index in the staging table to help the left join.

It has the same code in three environments and we even restore the databases in dev and test from a backup from prod, so it have the same data. The resources are better in the production server. All the same version of SQL Server.

The DBA verify the indexes and statistics and rebuild some, but it didn't fix the issue.
I also tried to changed the SSIS to a stored procedure, but it took even longer. With the stored procedure, we saw that the first 8 000 000 rows are fast (maybe 30 minutes), but after it takes like 1h30 to insert 1 000 000 rows. Only the log file is limited but to 2TB. Disks have plenty of free space.

Anybody have any idea why it's taking more than 12h longer in the production server?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you use `sp_whoisactive` to find out what it's waiting on. Your DBA should have already done this.

Comment: Is the SSIS Server the same as the SQL Server? Are you running out of memory? Is the process blocked at the SQL Server end or the SSIS end?

Comment: Usually if not always the size/amount of data in PROD is vastly greater than lower environments which could account for the time difference.  Have you looked at execution plans?  Checked out indexes?

Comment: SSIS uses any available system (RAM) memory outside of what is already reserved for SQL Server. I suspect the changes to the query increased the memory required above what is available. It might help to check how much memory was provided outside of SQL Server on test versus production.

Comment: Step 1 is to compare the query plans from your dev/test servers to the query plan on your production server.

Comment: How many non-clustered indexes exist on the target table - do they exist in the lower environments? For a truncate and reload pattern, you'll generally be better served by dropping any *non-clustered* indexes before loading and creating afterwards. The advice to run `sp_whoisactive` is always excellent advice. Find out why the process is behaving differently and report back so we can advise on mitigation.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The SSIS and SQL are on the same server. Don't see any blocks.

Comment: @Brad Since we restored the prod database in dev and test environments, the data and indexes are the same.

Comment: @billinkc There is no indexes in the target table.
For the memory, I will need to verify. But I know that the prod have almost double if not double, at least on the server. The configurations should be similar.

Comment: I am not very sure if this will faster your loading speed but worth a try. use the `ADO.net` destination instead of `OLE.db`. And Like the others suggested, check the processes details when the package starts, see if it is blocked or any processes runs over it.